# I am not able to zoom my responsive site in IPhone/IPAD

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am not able to zoom my responsive site in IPhone and IPAD.But at the same time I am not having any problem with Android mobiles. It is perfectly zooming in and zooming out.
I am having the meta tag like this

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much says it all on its own:

```
user-scalable=0
```

The Safari Web Content Guide tells us to use this when we want "to set the initial scale and to turn off user scaling." This is what prevents you from zooming in and out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So I can change that user-scalable=1.0 right??? but still I am not getting any change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the last 3 atrributes,

```
, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0
```

entirely.

That should allow Mobile Safari users to scale if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set "minimum-scale=1.0" to whatever you want your users to be able to zoom to (as well as setting the "user-scalable" to 1), for example: 2.0 would 100% zoom.